# string in the search box for webview21

Tags: string, search, getelementbyid, box, innertext

with old WebBrowser1

I can make WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("htlm string").InnerText = TextBox1.Text

where htlm string is the string for find the search box of google or other engine search

in this case the value of TextBox1.Text  appear  in the search box of google

I would make the same with  webview21!

Someone can help me ?

I don't know how use Webview21 to copy my string in a search box of google!